# Sequential numbering in PHP

Tags: php

I want to create sequential numbering in PHP, how to do that?

example

```
0000009
```

next number

```
0000010
```

I have tried using sprintf or str_pad but I didn't get this format

```
sprintf('%08d', 1234567) + 1;
str_pad($value, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) + 1;
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your output. Just do: `echo sprintf("%07d", 9);` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop and precisely a while loop for that. Then after the number has been generated you use str_pad to add the number of zeros you want. But in the while loop you must have a criteria or else it will iterate over and over again. Example

```
$number = 1;

while ($number <= 10) {
    echo str_pad ($number, 7, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), '<br>';
    $number++; // or any rule you want.
}
```

That's it